# MySQL MAMP doesn't work

Tags: mysql, mamp

I have a problem with MAMP, I set the ports like this: 
Apache : 8888
MySQL: 8889
but MySQL doesn't works. So I read the mysql_error_log.err file, I have this:

```
> 161018 14:21:12 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56
2016-10-18 14:21:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-10-18 14:21:13 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.28) starting as process 6728 ...
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1600607 and 1600607 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1605546 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-10-18 14:21:13 6728 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_table_stats uses space ID: 1 at filepath: ./mysql/innodb_table_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace racehistory/users which uses space ID: 1 at filepath: ./racehistory/users.ibd
2016-10-18 14:21:13 7fff77000000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./racehistory/users.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
161018 14:21:13 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

but I don't understand what is this. But I saw in this line

```
> InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./racehistory/users.ibd
```

this is not my database's name, my database name is RaceHistory. Maybe the problem is here, but in this case I don't know how to change for MySQL, in PHPmyAdmin I created a database with the name: RaceHistory.
I tried to change the port of MySQL, I tried with 3300, 3306 and random ports, with 3300 it worked for a moment and it crash again.
So If you have any ideas !
Thank You ! (And sorry for my english)

EDIT: I try to start apache and mysql by terminal, so I went to /MAMP/bin and I do sh start.sh, it launch for apache, but for mysql I have this:

```
161018 15:45:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

So I went to tmp/mysql and I don't have mysql.pid file !

Comment: `InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Yes, but users.ibd is in race history's folder !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your error message provides some pretty good clues what to do next.

```
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./racehistory/users.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: I delete my file users.ibd once, and it worked, but when I create a table again the same mistake come back, so I don't want to delete my file again. And I try to change the permission chmod a+rw for my users.ibd and nothing changes.